# "Algorithmically", what does uniform continuity means?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I am a bit confused trying to understand what uniform continuity means, from the definition we have:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; \forall x \in X \; \forall y \in X : \, d_1(x,y) < \delta \, \Rightarrow \,d_2(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon$$

Let's say we set $f(x)=x^2$ with $x\in[1,2]$ and $\epsilon=1$. Then we have $|x^2-y^2|<1$, now we must pick a $\delta$ such that for any $|x-y|< \delta$ we have $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Is this correct?

---

I made a "finite experiment" like this: Suppose we pick $y_0=1, y_1=1.1, y_2=1.2,...,$ for each of these values of $y_i$, we must "solve" the following systems of inequalities:

$$|f(x)-f(y_i)|<1 \hspace{1cm} 1\leq x \leq 2  $$

for $x$, and then we get intervals such as:

$$x_i'< x_i < x_i''$$

Which are represented in the plot below, for the different values of $y_i$:

[image]

And then we must pick $\delta < \min\{x_1-x_1', x_1''-x_i,x_2-x_2', x_2''-x_2, \dots, x_n-x_n', x_n''-x_n\}$, because with this, we guarantee that whenever $x,y$ is in one of the intervals, $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\def\d{\delta}\def\e{\epsilon}$$ Sometimes people think that we're trying to get the best possible $\d$ for a given $\e$. That's not the point. The big difference is between some $\d$ working vs. no $\d$ working for a given $\e$. Here's a crude approach to proving that $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,2]$. We have $$ |f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2-y^2| = |x-y|\,|x+y| < |x-y| \, 10^{10}, $$ since $|x+y| < 10^{10}$ for all $x,y\in [1,2]$.

Having done some scratch work off to the side we're ready to proceed with our proof. Given $\e>0$ let $\d=\e/10^{10}$. Then for all $x,y\in [0,1]$ we have  $$ |x-y| < \d \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y| 10^{10} < \d \, 10^{10} = \e.$$

We've found a way of handling not just the finite list of inequalities you considered, but **all** such inequalities simultaneously. Did we get the best $\d$? No! Did we get a $\d$ that worked? Yes!

Comment: What would be the "best $\delta$"? Is it something like the minimum I mention at the end of my thought experiment?

Comment: Right. In this example replacing $10^{10}$ with $4$ gives an optimal $\delta$, which in this case one can prove. In general it's **extremely** difficult to figure out what an optimal $\delta$ would be.

Comment: But the procedure I gave would be "useful" for finding a best $\delta$? I want to know if what I thought make sense.

Comment: Yes, you were definitely thinking correctly about what needs to be true about $\delta$. Of course one has to deal with all $x$ in $[1,2]$, so no finite list of inequalities like yours can provide the answer. You need to let $x$ range over all of $[1,2]$, not just a finite list of possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, I was just making a thought experiment. But I was aware that I would need to do this for all numbers in $[1,2].$

Answer (score 1):

Uniform continuity is about functions that doesn't change too sharply. In fact, if you pick two points enough near, their images will be "near" too. However your first guess is correct.